# Public domain images of Little Fuzzy?

Tags: little-fuzzy

I've been rereading H. Beam Piper's "Little Fuzzy", and I had a thought for a t-shirt I might have made to wear to my next Con.

But it requires an image of Little Fuzzy.

Any ideas where I might find one?

Comment: Hmm. The story itself is now in the public domain. I'm not sure whether that also applies to the original book cover art: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Fuzzy - https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/10/LittleFuzzy.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Victor Kalin's artwork and prints are for sale by Rebecca Kalin, so I wouldn't count on that particular cover being out of copyright.

Comment: I'm not absolutely opposed to buying rights to the image, if it's cheap enough. I figure it'll cost me $20-30 to have a shirt printed, another $10 for the limited right to use the image in a t-shirt for personal use wouldn't disuade me. But any more than that would. I have lots of ideas for Con shirts, and a limited number of Cons.

Comment: I made a custom T-shirt as a gift a few years ago. It took me a while to find a printer who would print custom art at a reasonable size. Many of the big names have some surprisingly small size limits for custom art. I made the custom art myself and use only one color of ink for the printing. The results were great and it was $80 when all was said and done. If you create your own image of Fuzzy then you’re probably fine, as long as you interpret the text and not copy anyone else’s art. And you might not be happy with the bargain priced custom shirts.

Comment: I've had a number of 1-off custom t-shirts printed for a lot less than $80. Quality has been adequate, for something I'd only wear to a Con. It's not like I'd be caught dead anywhere else in a shirt blazoned with "Ygvi is a louse", etc.